# error: no matching function for call to 'strcmp' (Trying to set display userinfo function)

Tags: c++, fstream, strcmp

I am trying to create a function that displays details of user after they have signed up. Keep getting error about ***strcmp*** function.

> Note i'm getting from compiler: candidate function not 
>   viable: no known conversion
>        from 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka >'basic_string') to 'const char *' for 1st
>        argument

Code:

```
void display_uDetails(char n[])
{
std::cout<<"\nUSER DETAILS\n";
int flag=0;
fp.open("book.dat",ios::in);
while(fp.read((char*)&u,sizeof(createUser)))
{
    if(strcmp(u.retuname(),n)==0)
    {
        u.show_user();
        flag=1;
    }
}
fp.close();
if(flag==0)
    std::cout<<"\n\nUser does not exist!";
getch();
}
```

Update:

The error is coming from my retuname() function here:

```
char* retuname()
{
    return uname;
}
```

**Display function:**

```
void display_uDetails(char n[])
{
    std::cout<<"\nUSER DETAILS\n";
    int flag=0;
    fp.open("book.dat",ios::in);
    while(fp.read((char*)&cu,sizeof(createUser)))
    {
      if(cu.retuname() == n)
      {
        cu.show_user();
        flag=1;
      }
}
fp.close();
if(flag==0)
    std::cout<<"\n\nUser does not exist!";
getch();
}
```

> It says *error: no viable conversion from returned value of type > 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string') to function return type 'char *'
>                   return uname;
>                         ^~~~~*

**'cu' Class definition**

```
class createUser
{
   string uname;
   string pword;
   string name;
};
```

Defining createUser class as **'cu'** & declaring stream

```
// global declaration for stream object, object 

 fstream fp, fp1;
 createUser cu;
```

Comment: very similar question asked not so long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59036335/how-can-i-alphabetize-strings-from-an-array-in-c

Comment: `fp.read((char*)&u,sizeof(createUser))` what is `createUser` hopefully its a POD type. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

Comment: @drescherjm yes it is a POD type

Comment: Your errors and the shown code doesn't make sense together.

Comment: I'm also worried that `uname` might be a pointer which make the whole file reading wrong.

Comment: Take another look. I added the updated code from the display function @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @drescherjm I am clueless then. When i run the program it is the only error i am getting

Comment: `if(cu.retuname() == n)` you can't use `==` with char arrays / c-strings. This will compare pointers not the c-string.

Comment: ***When i run the program it is the only error i am getting*** Maybe you did not save your changes and its compiling an old version of your code. The error still does not make sense.

Comment: @drescherjm But it can't be or the first error originally asked about wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @Dame It's still not a [mcve]. What is `u`? What is the class or structure definition used?

Comment: Didn't think to add that in. **u** is the class definition, it is now defined as **cu**

Comment: @Dame `u` in the first example, `cu` in the second... Which is it *really*? Again, we can't help you if you don't show us a [mcve].

Comment: the second example clearly says **UPDATED** meaning things were adjusted @Someprogrammerdude it is **'cu'**

Comment: `createUser` is not a `POD` type. So the read will not work. You can not serialize a structure containing a std::string this way. That will not cause the error however.

Comment: Now the second error makes sense: `uname` is of type `std::string` while your return type for the function is `char *`. That's an invalid combination. ***But*** that return type of the function doesn't make sense with the *first* error. There's just to many inconsistencies in the question, the code and the errors. Please refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And try to to create a [mcve] that we can replicate the errors ourselves.

Comment: Is it that having private elements that makes it not a POD type? Damn learn more on here than from professors lol @drescherjm

Comment: ***Is it that having private elements that makes it not a POD type?*** That is not the problem. `std::string` contains internal pointers.

Comment: I think this should help with the POD determination: [https://ideone.com/gd9Cpv](https://ideone.com/gd9Cpv) taken from here: [http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/pod-types-in-c.html](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/pod-types-in-c.html)

Comment: @drescherjm got it to work. Just swapped strings with char and used strcmp as originally planned

Comment: Perhaps you need some more time with [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to learn C++ better? Don't treat C++ as "C with classes", use the functionality that C++ provides, like `std::string`, containers, algorithms and streams. And if you're required to work with raw binary files then remember to actually open them in binary mode, and use *serialization* to read and write the files from C++ classes and objects. Or just use plain-text files.

Comment: I just started 2 months ago. I am getting better with strings, but everything takes practice. I did not learn C yet so I don't believe I'll be treating it like that. Thanks for the books though.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error message it seems that `u.retuname()` is returning a `std::string`, which means you can't use `strcmp` to compare it.

But `std::string` have an overloaded `==` operator so you can compare it directly as

```
if (u.retuname() == n) { ... }
```

Comment: I did that and I am now looking at this error: no viable conversion from returned value of type
      'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to function return type 'char *'
                return uname;

Comment: Updated the problem above